# Cannot setState - tried with Axios, AJAX and fetch()

Tags: reactjs

bit of React noob here, and this one is escaping me, so thanks in advance for what is very likely an easy fix.

All I want to do is set the state of my courses component to take in the array from my API. I'm accessing the data fine, and it's showing me the array of four objects in the console, but the state simply won't change. What am I missing?

And before anyone asks me why I'm not using Redux it's because I want to understand the fundamentals first.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import axios from 'axios';
import $ from 'jquery';

class CourseIndex extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      courses: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.getCourses();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getCourses();
  }

  getCourses(){
// ============================ jquery()================================

    $.ajax(({
      url:'/courses',
      headers: {
        "Authorization": localStorage.getItem('id_token')
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
        this.setState({
          courses: data
        })
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    }))

    console.log(this.state);

// ============================ fetch()================================
    // fetch(
    //   '/courses',
    //   {
    //     headers: {
    //       "Authorization": localStorage.getItem('id_token')
    //     }
    //   })
    //   .then((res) => res.json())
    //   .then((data) => {
    //     this.setState({
    //       courses: data
    //     },console.log(this.state))
    //   });

    // ============================ axios()================================

    // axios
    //   .get(
    //     '/courses',
    //     {
    //       headers: {
    //         "Authorization": localStorage.getItem('id_token')
    //       }
    //     }
    //   )
    //   // .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    //   .then(res =>
    //     this.setState({
    //       courses: res
    //     }, console.log(this.state))
    //   )
    //   .catch(err => console.log(err));

    // console.log(this.state.courses);

    // const items = this.courses.map(res => (
    //   <li className="list-group-item">
    //     <h3>{ res.name }</h3>
    //   </li>
    // ))
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CourseIndex;
```

Sorry for the commented out code, by the way - I was just experimenting with the different calling modules.

Thanks

Comment: How do you check that state is not changed? With the `console.log` in your fetch methods? Then don't use it like that since `setState` is async. Check your state in your `render` method. I don't know `jQuery` part with `axios` one you can't set the state like that since you are not returning anything from `then` method right before the setting state. But `fetch` one seems ok.

Comment: I was doing console.log() in the lifecycle methods, not the render - it was working after all. Duh! I feel like a dunce. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.ajax` is asynchronous, so you cannot log the state before the request has finished and expect the state to have changed. `setState` itself is also asynchronous, so if you want to log the state after it has been changed, you can use the second argument to `setState` which is a callback function. You are currently invoking `console.log` straight away, but you want to give a function *that will be invoked*.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/courses",
  headers: {
    Authorization: localStorage.getItem("id_token")
  },
  dataType: "json",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    this.setState(
      {
        courses: data
      },
      () => console.log(this.state)
    );
  }.bind(this),
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Turns out it was setting the state but I was trying to console.log from the lifecycle, not the render. Still got a LOT to learn about React.